# combining results from two different cursors and then writing to a csv file in python 3

Tags: python-3.x, sql-server-2012, cursor, export-to-csv

I am new to Python and I am working on a script that generates a csv report that writes data from the database, when given an ID as input. It works fine with one cursor.Now I have two different databases and I want to generate a single report that combines the results of both cursors. How do I combine the results from each cursor horizontally ? Is that possible in python 3? Please give me some suggestions. Here is the code I am working which involves one cursor:

```
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("Select * from FailureAnalysisResults where LotName = ? and TestResultID = ?", (lot_name, testResultID))

with open(csvfile, 'w', newline='') as fout:
    writer = csv.writer(fout, delimiter=',', quotechar=' ', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    writer.writerow([i[0] for i in cur.description])  # heading row
    writer.writerows(cur.fetchall())
```

I want to do the above for another database and combine the results of both the cursors before writing it to the csv file. I tried checking out arrays but I am stuck and need some suggestions. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Well , I could achieve the above asked with the following code snippet:

```
list1 = list(cur1)
list2 = list(cur2)

list3 = list(zip(list1, list2))
with open(csvfile, 'w', newline='') as fout:
    writer = csv.writer(fout, delimiter=',', quotechar=' ', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    writer.writerow([i[0] for i in cur1.description] + [j[0] for j in cur2.description])  # heading row

   writer.writerows(list3)
```

The above code concatenates well but I have formatting issues in the.csv file generated. It also prints  '(',',',')' in the csv file which is  causing some formatting issues.